# Confused with variable scope for this particular program

Tags: java

This is a snippet of my code. I already fixed this bug, but I just don't understand why it works now. I'm not sure if I explained this correctly, so please ask any question if necessary. The bug is that the variable *puncation* changes to the correct value *test* when the statement is located in the place where I commented, the statement works. But, it does not work when the statement is located in the place where I commented, the statement does not work.

```
     if (endOfSen) {
                /////////////////The statement below works when it is here./////////////
                /////////////////OUTPUT 1 - occurs when the statement is placed here.              
                 String puncation = null ;
                /////////////////////
                int orgSize = words.size(); //remember size of stack
                //only runs if stack is not empty
                if (!words.empty()) {
                    while (words.size() > 0) {      //until last word
                        String word = words.pop();
                        ///The statement below does not work when it is here///////
                        //////OUTPUT 2- occurs when the statement is placed here.  
                        //String puncation = null ;

                        //if last word of sentence
                        if (orgSize == words.size() + 1) {
                            word = word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
                            puncation = "test";     // just a test value
                            word = word.replace(puncation, "");
                            //////////////////test to see if works 
                            System.out.println("puncation: " + puncation);
                        }
                        //if first word of sentence
                        if (words.size() == 0) {
                            //////////////////test to see if works 
                            System.out.println("puncation: " + puncation);
                            word = word.toLowerCase();
                            word = word + "" + puncation;
                        }
                        newSen.push(word);
                    }
                }
                endOfSen = false;
            }
        }
```

OUTPUT 1 (Second *puncation* changes from original value)

```
puncation: test
puncation: test
```

Output 2 (Second *puncation* does not change from original value)

```
puncation: test
puncation: null
```

Comment: what was the bug? What did you change?

Comment: please specify when output 1 occurs and when output 2 occurs

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus I made an edit, not sure if it helped.

Comment: yep. so the code now (with the commented out line) is working, right?

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus yes, that is correct. If that statement is not commented out and the statement under output 1 is commented out then the program does not work correctly, hence output 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable is declared inside the loop, then each iteration of the loop will see a *different* variable. Besides, you even initialize it to null when there, so each iteration will start with a null value.

When declared to null outside the loop, the variable will retain the value from previous iteration(s) of the loop.

Since `orgSize` never changes in the loop, and `words` shrinks by one each iteration, the first `if` statement can only ever be true on the first iteration. Second `if` statement can only ever be true on the last iteration.

So if `puncation` is initialized to null inside the loop, the only time it can be not null in the second `if` statement would be if `words` originally had size 1.

Simple debugging could have shown you all this.

Comment: Dammit, it seems so obvious now. And true, I should have just hand written what the program was doing and I would have seen what was going on. Well, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not as much a scoping issue as it's just that the variable is being reset in the loop. I made an example below that is more explicit about the value being reset.

```
if (endOfSen) {

        /////////////////The statement below works when it is here./////////////
        /////////////////OUTPUT 1 //////////////////
        String puncation = null ;
        /////////////////////
        int orgSize = words.size(); //remember size of stack
        //only runs if stack is not empty
        if (!words.empty()) {
            while (words.size() > 0) {      //until last word
                String word = words.pop();
                ///The statement below does not work when it is here///////
                /////////////////OUTPUT 2 //////////////////

                // Puncation is beign reset here, each iteration of the loop
                puncation = null ;

                //if last word of sentence
                if (orgSize == words.size() + 1) {
                    word = word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
                    puncation = "test";     // just a test value
                    word = word.replace(puncation, "");
                    //////////////////test to see if works 
                    System.out.println("puncation: " + puncation);
                }
                //if first word of sentence
                if (words.size() == 0) {
                    //////////////////test to see if works 
                    System.out.println("puncation: " + puncation);
                    word = word.toLowerCase();
                    word = word + "" + puncation;
                }
                newSen.push(word);
            }
        }
        endOfSen = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really explain *why*.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the other comment it seems so obvious now. Thanks for your answer though.